# How to structure the storage of images in a PHP gallery

Tags: php, mysql, gallery, laravel-5

I am creating a new gallery for my history website using PHP/MySQL and Laravel, although that is for reference in this question.

What I am wondering is how to structure the storage for all the images uploaded to the gallery, I have looked at some popular web galleries and others but they all appear to differ.

For some the folder structure where they store the images is simply something like.

Gallery
-Images

So all images and thumbnails are stored simply in the Images directory.

I have also seen the following which perhaps make sense to separate image and thumbnails

Gallery
- Images
- Thumbnails

And then the extreme.

Gallery
- Category
-- Sub Category
--- Thumbnails

The last example seems very extreme, you would have a minimum of 3 folders per category, but if you had 10 categories each with 10 more sub categories, that is 210 folders, it seems way too much.

So really looking for some insight from those that have worked with galleries as to what the best approach is.

I feel that MySQL is your organiser, it should determine what image is assigned to which category and sub category and organise the results as required.  I can't really see any benefit of more than 1 folder, 2 at best just to separate the thumbnails.

Really not sure to be honest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult to answer given we don't know anything about the organization of your history site.

I've seen it done in a multitude of ways from storing everything with a time/date format name all in the same folder and keeping the files actual names in an sql database to be translated by the PHP.

I've never seen any sort of standard exactly. If your site is small, and not handling user uploads it would probably make the most sense to do it by the following folder setup so coming back at a future time you can add multiple events to the same day and rely on file names for more specific information.

```
Gallery
- Date_of_history_event
-- Name_of_history_event
-- Name_of_history_event
-- Name_of_history_event
- Date_of_history_event
-- Name_of_history_event
-- Name_of_history_event
```

edit* If you wanted to keep separate the thumbs maybe do something like this:

```
Gallery
- Date_of_history_event
-- Name_of_history_event
--- Thumbs
--- Images
-- Name_of_history_event
--- Thumbs
--- Images
-- Name_of_history_event
--- Thumbs
--- Images
- Date_of_history_event
-- Name_of_history_event
--- Thumbs
--- Images
-- Name_of_history_event
--- Thumbs
--- Images
```

Comment: In terms of what I have it is a Holocaust history site.  Quite straight forward with top level categories and then sub categories.    

However a folder for everything still seems overkill, it's the benefit I can't see even of doing what you have suggested other than for aesthetics unless there is another benefit.

Comment: @SCC-Lee  It may seem overkill, but there are a good number of reasons to use a more complex folder structure. Some dive right into basic hardware data storage methods. Consider the resource hog it becomes to have a very large number of files/folders in the same folder in any GUI. It's less intense on a text based system, but is still a good practice. Don't be surprised if you come back to use this again in the future for some larger purpose. You may be very grateful you took the time! Anything worth doing, is worth doing right.

Comment: Absolutely agree, I am still considering the options before I complete the setup for the gallery, thanks for you advice.